# Javascript unit testing with Jasmine and JSP

Tags: javascript, maven, unit-testing, jsp, jasmine

I am working on a project that uses JSP and Javascript. Now I have to write unit tests so I started using Jasmine for it and since the project is built using Maven,  My goal was to run unit tests as part of continuous build and integration. So I thought of using jasmine-maven-plugin it uses PhantomJS for headless testing. I tried PhantomJS API to see whether it can load a JSP based webpage. Using the sample api I was able to create a screenshot of my JSP page. So I think PhantomJS can work with JSP.

My unit tests are heavily dependent on the JSP page but I was to not able to configure the Jasmine specRunner to use JSP, so that I can run my Jasmine tests as part of maven build.

Does anybody used Jasmine, Javascript, JSP combination for unit testing? Any help or comments will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is in your JSP that you're trying to test?

Comment: The JSP is bundled in a war which calls my javascript code and my app downloads and unpacks this war as part of build step. Its like my app is a tiny jQuery/ Javascript component that uses this JSP application framework. So to test any functionality the JSP framework has to be preloaded. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: And you can't mock the values?